# Angular 11 template parse errors : not a known element

Tags: angular, angular-module

As title,I'm trying to use another same level component in current component,but facing this errors.

### DevTools gave me two solutions

- If 'message-block' is an Angular component,then vertify that it is part of this module.
- If 'message-block' is a Web component,then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENT_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schema' of this component to suppress this message.

### Folder

- block

  - customerProfile

    - profileBlock

      - profileInfo

        - profileInfo.html
        - profileInfo.ts
      - profileBlock.module.ts
  - message-block
- block.modules.ts

### Modules

Here is my block module

```
@NgModel({
  imports:[...otherModule],
  declarations:[messageBlockComponents],
  export:[messageBlockComponents]
})
```

- I've check the message-block component's selector name is right

```
<message-block></message-block>
```

The errors is happening in **profileInfo.html**.I have declare message-block in block moodule,and it's a parent module,so I don't add any declartion in profileBlock.modules.

### Question

How do I add message-block into profileInfo component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Reason

The reason that cause this error is that same layer component cannot identify each other,unless they have their own module to manage themself.

### Solution

so I create a module for message-block.Let the block.module and profileBlock.module both import message-block module.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).